# Not getting Report Model Query Designer in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am working on SQL Server reporting Service(SSRS) with Report Builder 3. I successfully connected Data Source with Oracle Server. When I working in Report Builder I did not find Report Model Query Designer. How can I find this?

Please see this link: (As I need at least 10 reputation to post image)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345246.aspx

How can it possible to merge dataset with datasource (database entity) in SSRS?

Comment: Data source is the connection (oracle) dataset is the query or stored procedure...what do you mean by merge?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got the whole answer of my question by searching. Now I can understand my criteria is I want to create a report model in visual studio 2010. but there is no option in visual studion 2010. It is available in Visual Studio 2008. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the whole answer of my question by searching. Now I can understand my criteria is I want to create a report model in Visual Studio 2010. but there is no option in visual studio 2010. It is available in Visual Studio 2008 which will fulfil my demand.

For viewers, after installing Visual Studio 2008, create report model and deploy in Report server.

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/09/working-with-report-model-in-ssrs-part.html

Then when you use Data Source in Report Builder you will get the Report Model Query Designer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing a new solution based on Report Models please be aware that this is a deprecated feature in SQL Server 2012 and will not be supported in future versions.